# Asp.Net Core 2 - audio files from and to the database

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently creating a web application that is supposed to play sound files.
The first problem I have encountered is the fact that when writing audio files to a database, all records have the same value even though they are different audio files, [database with audio files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z0yK.png)

I'm not sure if it saves it in a good way, but I wanted to do it in the same way as with pictures

```
Mp3 mp3 = new Mp3();
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await createViewModel.Name_mp3.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                mp3.Name_mp3 = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            _context.Mp3.Add(mp3);
            _context.SaveChanges();
```

Please, give me a hint as to whether it should look like this

---

The second question is how to extract these audio files from the database. I also tried the way in which pictures were extracted from the database.

So my view looks like this

```
    @model IEnumerable<inz.Models.Song>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div class="panelDiv textColor">
    <form asp-controller="Songs" asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <div class="input-group w-50 m-4 mx-auto">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg border-danger searchBorder" placeholder="Wyszukaj utwór lub artyste" name="search" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
            <div class="dropdown w-0">
                <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu bg-danger" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <input type="submit" name="all" value="Wyświetl wszystko" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="text-center m-5">
        <a asp-action=Create>
            <buton class="textColor btnDiv">
                Dodaj nowy utwór <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>
            </buton>
        </a>
    </div>
    @if (ViewBag.ShowList == true)
    {
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table tableSong">
                <thead class="bg-danger table-borderless">
                    <tr>
                        <th>

                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Album.Name_Album)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Artist.Name_Artist)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                                &nbsp;
                                &nbsp;
                                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.Album.Name_Album != null)
                                {
                                    <a asp-controller="Songs" asp-action="Album" asp-route-nameAlbum="@item.Album.Name_Album" class="link">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Album.Name_Album)</a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span>Brak informacji</span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-controller="Songs" asp-action="Artist" asp-route-name="@item.Artist.Name_Artist" class="link">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artist.Name_Artist)</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID_Song">
                                    <buton class="textColor btnIndex">Edytuj</buton>
                                </a>
                                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID_Song">
                                    <buton class="textColor btnIndex">Detale</buton>
                                </a>

                                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                                {
                                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID_Song">
                                        <buton class="textColor btnIndex">Usuń</buton>
                                    </a>
                                }   
                            </td>
                            **<td>
                                @{
                                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Mp3.Name_mp3);
                                    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:audio/mp3;base64,{0}", base64);
                                }
                                <audio controls>
                                    <source src="@imgSrc" type="audio/ogg" />
                                </audio>
                            </td>**
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>



        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <p class="mt-5"> Brak zawartości do wyświetlenia</p>
    }
</div>
```

But I still have an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqfyW.png)

I will add what my models look like

```
public class Mp3
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID_Mp3 { get; set; }

        public byte[] Name_mp3 { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class CreateViewModel
    {
        public int ID_Song { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę wpisać tytuł")]
        [Display(Name = "Tytuł")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę wpisać nazwę artysty")]
        [Display(Name = "Artysta")]
        public string Name_Artist { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Album")]
        public string Name_Album { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Producent")]
        public string Name_Producer { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Name_mp3 { get; set; }
    }
```

I am asking for hints and I apologize for my English

Comment: Just a suggestion, have you thought about using blob storage instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that storing the audio files in the database it's a good idea.

You could instead save the file on disk, then save the path.

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Path { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Registered{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RegisteredBy { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

To save the file:

```
using (var db = new EFModel())
{
    if (file.Id == Guid.Empty)
    {
        file.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        db.Entry(file).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
        db.Entry(file).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
    return archivo;
}
```

In the save button/action:

```
if (!fuArchivo.HasFile)
    throw new UserException("Debes seleccionar un archivo.");

string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fuArchivo.FileName);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fuArchivo.FileName);

string pathArchivo = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rutaCarga"],
    ae.IdTitulo.ToString(), ae.IdArchivoEtapa.ToString());
if (!Directory.Exists(pathArchivo))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathArchivo);
pathArchivo = Path.Combine(pathArchivo, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension);

fuArchivo.SaveAs(pathArchivo);
if (File.Exists(pathArchivo))
{
    var archivo = new File()
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty,
        RegisteredBy = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name,
        Registered = DateTime.Now,
        Name = nombreArchivo,
        Path = pathArchivo
    };
    var on = new FileBO();
    return on.Save(archivo);
}
else
    throw new Exception("Se guardó el archivo pero no existe.");
```

Sorry, it's in spanish. Hope this helps.